# My MacBook Pro OS X Version 10.10 keeps crashing ~ HELP!

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, crash

My MacBook Pro OS X Yosemite Version 10.10 (5 years old at least) keeps crashing and I don't know what to do? I run an online business and it is becoming impossible to look after as my computer keeps crashing. I upgraded to Yosemite in the hope that my computer would stop crashing, but it is now crashing every few minutes. HELP!!!

```
Anonymous UUID:       03D20D83-C369-6889-8AFE-339E55ABB860

Fri Oct 24 14:25:53 2014

*** Panic Report ***
panic(cpu 1 caller 0xffffff7f9fb64f63): "GPU Panic: [<None>] 5 3 7f 0 0 0 0 3 : NVRM[0/1:0:0]: Read Error 0x00610210: CFG 0xffffffff 0xffffffff 0xffffffff, BAR0 0xd2000000 0xffffff8138d88000 0x0a5480a2, D0, P2/4\n"@/SourceCache/AppleGraphicsControl/AppleGraphicsControl-3.7.21/src/AppleMuxControl/kext/GPUPanic.cpp:127
Backtrace (CPU 1), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff811e92b060 : 0xffffff801cf3a811 
0xffffff811e92b0e0 : 0xffffff7f9fb64f63 
0xffffff811e92b1c0 : 0xffffff7f9db44b9f 
0xffffff811e92b280 : 0xffffff7f9dc0e18e 
0xffffff811e92b2c0 : 0xffffff7f9ddc60e5 
0xffffff811e92b2f0 : 0xffffff7f9ddc6e10 
0xffffff811e92b330 : 0xffffff7f9db21790 
0xffffff811e92b450 : 0xffffff7f9db2216c 
0xffffff811e92b4e0 : 0xffffff7f9db1f52b 
0xffffff811e92b520 : 0xffffff7f9db1f49b 
0xffffff811e92b5c0 : 0xffffff7f9db491fa 
0xffffff811e92b7c0 : 0xffffff7f9db4a07a 
0xffffff811e92b8a0 : 0xffffff7f9f144446 
0xffffff811e92b8e0 : 0xffffff7f9f153dff 
0xffffff811e92b900 : 0xffffff7f9f182493 
0xffffff811e92b930 : 0xffffff7f9f1824ed 
0xffffff811e92b970 : 0xffffff7f9f159a1f 
0xffffff811e92b9c0 : 0xffffff7f9f124027 
0xffffff811e92ba60 : 0xffffff7f9f11fda1 
0xffffff811e92ba90 : 0xffffff7f9f11d873 
0xffffff811e92bad0 : 0xffffff801d50064c 
0xffffff811e92bb60 : 0xffffff801d502773 
0xffffff811e92bbc0 : 0xffffff801d500003 
0xffffff811e92bd00 : 0xffffff801cfea517 
0xffffff811e92be10 : 0xffffff801cf3e91c 
0xffffff811e92be40 : 0xffffff801cf235a3 
0xffffff811e92be90 : 0xffffff801cf33e8d 
0xffffff811e92bf10 : 0xffffff801d00a142 
0xffffff811e92bfb0 : 0xffffff801d03ac66 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl(3.7.21)[32B7E2DE-1F9D-3555-B687-7A76A62B81D2]@0xffffff7f9fb56000->0xffffff7f9fb69fff
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl(3.7.21)[62689710-EEA7-307A-AC83-B8F25DA88A6A]@0xffffff7f9fb4e000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily(1.4)[70E2B65E-A91A-3522-A1A0-79FD63EABB4C]@0xffffff7f9da2b000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[766FC23F-452C-3B74-951C-598BB17BCF06]@0xffffff7f9d724000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.4.1)[6D99A3BE-D531-3780-880B-13F2FC894A4A]@0xffffff7f9da9d000
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert(1.1.0)[0183904C-6A16-32C4-9405-EEFD7F820B02]@0xffffff7f9fb51000
         com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDAResmanTesla(10.0)[796AE430-39FB-3255-8161-D52AFA28EE2B]@0xffffff7f9daf4000->0xffffff7f9dd5dfff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[766FC23F-452C-3B74-951C-598BB17BCF06]@0xffffff7f9d724000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport(2.4.1)[F4738C55-B507-3627-A9CA-3D29A5230A03]@0xffffff7f9dae4000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.4.1)[6D99A3BE-D531-3780-880B-13F2FC894A4A]@0xffffff7f9da9d000
         com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDANV50HalTesla(10.0)[7FE40648-F15F-3E18-91E2-FDDDF4CDA355]@0xffffff7f9dd68000->0xffffff7f9e011fff
            dependency: com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDAResmanTesla(10.0.0)[796AE430-39FB-3255-8161-D52AFA28EE2B]@0xffffff7f9daf4000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[766FC23F-452C-3B74-951C-598BB17BCF06]@0xffffff7f9d724000
         com.apple.GeForceTesla(10.0)[67CD214F-0F26-3BEF-BAD0-CF0F83C2616D]@0xffffff7f9f101000->0xffffff7f9f1cefff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[766FC23F-452C-3B74-951C-598BB17BCF06]@0xffffff7f9d724000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport(2.4.1)[F4738C55-B507-3627-A9CA-3D29A5230A03]@0xffffff7f9dae4000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.4.1)[6D99A3BE-D531-3780-880B-13F2FC894A4A]@0xffffff7f9da9d000
            dependency: com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDAResmanTesla(10.0.0)[796AE430-39FB-3255-8161-D52AFA28EE2B]@0xffffff7f9daf4000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: WindowServer
Boot args: arch=i386

Mac OS version:
14A389

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 14.0.0: Fri Sep 19 00:26:44 PDT 2014; root:xnu-2782.1.97~2/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 89E10306-BC78-3A3B-955C-7C4922577E61
Kernel slide:     0x000000001cc00000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff801ce00000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff801cd00000
System model name: MacBookPro6,2 (Mac-F22586C8)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 1698055313331
last loaded kext at 73953239253: com.apple.driver.AppleHWSensor 1.9.5d0 (addr 0xffffff7f9f87d000, size 36864)
last unloaded kext at 276533560608: com.apple.driver.AppleUSBUHCI   656.4.1 (addr 0xffffff7f9e316000, size 65536)
loaded kexts:
com.globaldelight.driver.BoomDevice 1.1
com.apple.driver.AppleHWSensor  1.9.5d0
com.apple.driver.AGPM   100.14.37
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    4.3.0f10
com.apple.driver.AppleOSXWatchdog   1
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver    124
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver   266.5
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   266.5
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    2.0.4d1
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 4.3.0f10
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.70
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.1
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHWAccess  1
com.apple.driver.AppleHV    1
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.6.1
com.apple.GeForceTesla  10.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   1.7.3
com.apple.driver.ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHDGraphics   10.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHDGraphicsFB 10.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl    3.7.21
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.2.10
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCPDRC   1.0.0
com.apple.driver.SMCMotionSensor    3.0.4d1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons  240.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard 240.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCardReader 3.5.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIRController  327.5
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0d1
com.apple.BootCache 35
com.apple.iokit.SCSITaskUserClient  3.7.0
com.apple.driver.XsanFilter 404
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  2.6.5
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHub    705.4.1
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4331   800.20.24
com.apple.driver.AppleFWOHCI    5.5.2
com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet    10.1.2b3
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  3.0.7
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBEHCI   705.4.14
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 218.0.0
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   161
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  8
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement   218.0.0
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.7.21
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  11
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireIP    2.2.6
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 266.5
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    1.15
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   4.3.0f10
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   97
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   4.3.0f10
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   200.6
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.2.0
com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDANV50HalTesla   10.0.0
com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDAResmanTesla    10.0.0
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginLegacy 1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl   3.7.21
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.13d1
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 5.8.0d49
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient 705.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 266.5
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 266.5
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI  1.0.12d1
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.9
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch 245.2
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice   3.7.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageClass   3.7.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver  705.4.0
com.apple.driver.CoreStorage    471
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub   705.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBComposite  705.4.9
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIMultimediaCommandsDevice  3.7.0
com.apple.iokit.IOBDStorageFamily   1.7
com.apple.iokit.IODVDStorageFamily  1.7.1
com.apple.iokit.IOCDStorageFamily   1.7.1
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCISerialATAPI   2.6.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   3.7.0
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   700.52
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireFamily    4.5.6
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.0.3b3
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.2
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    2.7.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 705.4.14
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  300.0
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity   1.0.5
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 389.1
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  31
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  3.1
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
com.apple.kec.Libm  1
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
Model: MacBookPro6,2, BootROM MBP61.0057.B0F, 2 processors, Intel Core i7, 2.8 GHz, 8 GB, SMC 1.58f17
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics, Intel HD Graphics, Built-In, 288 MB
Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce GT 330M, NVIDIA GeForce GT 330M, PCIe, 512 MB
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1067 MHz, 0x802C, 0x31364A53533531323634485A2D3147314131
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1067 MHz, 0x802C, 0x31364A53533531323634485A2D3147314131
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x93), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (5.106.98.100.24)
Bluetooth: Version 4.3.0f10 14890, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: AirPort, AirPort, en1
Serial ATA Device: WDC WD10JPVT-55A1YT0, 1 TB
Serial ATA Device: MATSHITADVD-R   UJ-898
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: BRCM2070 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
USB Device: Internal Memory Card Reader
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: Built-in iSight
USB Device: IR Receiver
Thunderbolt Bus:
```

Comment: any issues with the display like distortions, partly black screens or strange coloured artefacts before the system crashes?

Comment: Ugh - constant crashes usually mean a restore from your last good backup. Do you have a backup?

Comment: Hi there klanomath ~ I get the rare glitch in the mail application ( usually a small grey triangle) and when it shuts down, the black screen isn't black instantly (it flashes semi black for a mili-second).

Comment: Hi bmike ~ I did have a Time Machine but the power section failed, so I haven't had a back up for 450 or so days unfortunately.

Comment: I suspect your nvidia graphic chip to die. Please download gfxCardStatus http://gfx.io/downloads/gfxCardStatus-2.3.zip, unzip it, put the resulting file in your application folder and start the app. Now click on the new menu bar item, choose 'Preferences' and enable 'Use smart menu bar icons' & 'Load gfxCardStatus at startup' in the 'General' tab. Now enable 'integrated' until 'integrated' (i) is chosen. It may take up to 3 times to enable it because of a glitch in the app. Now your intel instead of the nvidia graphic chip does the whole work. Report back if it still crashes.

Comment: You have to enable the integrated chip after every restart before any other application is launched.

Answer (score 4):

Your GPU is dying. Only a replacement plan from Apple can help you. But I doubt that it is near. At least you are not alone ;-). https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4766577?start=9495

And now there even is an extended warranty program: http://arstechnica.com/apple/2015/02/apple-launches-repair-program-for-longstanding-2011-macbook-pro-gpu-problems/

You can get to a more or less workable state by reverting back to Mavericks using a backup and then disabling the kernel extensions that are needed by the GPU:

It will force the system to use Intel HD 3000 Graphics. But at least you can boot, do some work and / or recover files. Reboot your computer and hold CMD + S, and type and press enter the following commands:

- /sbin/mount -uw /
- mkdir /System/Library/DisabledExtensions/
- mv /System/Library/Extensions/AMD* /System/Library/DisabledExtensions/
- mv /System/Library/Extensions/ATI* /System/Library/DisabledExtensions/
- Reboot by typing 'reboot' and enter.

If you need to restore the drivers:

- Boot normally, and from OSX open a Terminal window.
- sudo mv /System/Library/DisabledExtensions/* /System/Library/Extensions/
- sudo reboot

Downsides:

- Can't adjust screen brightness;
- Machine won't sleep. Need to shut it down before bagging it;
- Can't adjust any external display;
- Graphics performance is CPU only, so it's quite slow.

Answer (score 2):

Apple has a helpful article on Kernel Panics which is what you appear to be experiencing:

- http://support.apple.com/kb/HT200553 - OS X: When your computer spontaneously restarts or displays "Your computer restarted because of a problem."

I would step through that and post back here a new question once you have a specific step that is failing or you don't know how to proceed in that checklist of things to do.

Comment: Thank you bmike ~ I went on there and I tried clearing the RAM using Command / Option / p / r and it turned off and on, so I assumed it worked. I also started it in recovery mode, and it didn't crash. Does this mean it's a softwear problem? What do I do?